# FQL: query for event table returns venue.name instead of venue.id

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

When making a query to get event details I seem to get venue.name instead of venue.id in the result set. Has there been an unannounced change in the table structure or am I doing something wrong. The Graph API Explorer gives the venue.id yet when using FQL through PHP SDK in my own web site it's the venue.name I get.

Heres the code:

```
$fql='{
"event_info": "SELECT name,description, pic_small,pic_big, eid,venue,location FROM event WHERE eid ='.$_GET['id'].'", 
"event_venue":"SELECT name, username, page_id, location FROM page WHERE name IN (SELECT venue.id FROM #event_info)"
}';

    $setup  =   array(
    'method'    => 'fql.multiquery',
    'queries'     => $fql,
    'callback'  => ''
    );

    $result   =   $facebook->api($setup);
```

This leads to the "event_venue" result set to be empty.

Here's the dump:

```
Array
(    
    [0] => Array
         (
            [name] => event_info
        [fql_result_set] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [eid] => 410351692336116
                        [venue] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Boothill 
                            )

                        [location] => Boothill
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => event_venue
        [fql_result_set] => Array
            (
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump` of `$result` and show us what exactly it contains? (Relevant parts; and please update your question with that info, because inside the comments it will get hard to read.)

Comment: Dump added with relevant parts.

Answer (score 2):

If I test this query

```
SELECT name,description, pic_small,pic_big, eid,venue,location
  FROM event WHERE eid ='410351692336116'
```

using the FQL tab (!) in the Graph API explorer, I get

```
"venue": {
  "id": 126049334121592
}
```

and not the venue’s name.

And doing a multiquery like your’s with the second query being

```
"event_venue":"SELECT name, username, page_id, location FROM page
  WHERE page_id IN (SELECT venue.id FROM #event_info)"
```

I’m getting the venue info as well.

Could you please check if you get a different result if you do your queries not using your $setup array with

```
'method'    => 'fql.multiquery',
```

but just

```
$facebook->api('/fql?q='.urlencode('{ "event_info": "…", "event_venue": "… FROM page
  WHERE page_id IN (SELECT venue.id FROM #event_info)" }'));
```

instead?

Comment: No change. It gives the venue.name still. And yes the FQL tab in the Graph API explorer it has always given the venue.id as it should.

Comment: Strange. This return anything for you when used with the Graph API Explorer app? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3D%7B%22event_info%22%3A%20%22SELECT%20name%2Cdescription%2Cpic_small%2Cpic_big%2Ceid%2Cvenue%2Clocation%20FROM%20event%20WHERE%20eid%20%3D'410351692336116'%22%2C%22event_venue%22%3A%22SELECT%20name%2Cusername%2Cpage_id%2Clocation%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id%20IN%20(SELECT%20venue.id%20FROM%20%23event_info)%22%7D

Comment: Both the Graph API & FQL Query explorers return exactly what they should. Only when I run FQL queries on my own page it changes the venue id to the name. Really strange.

Comment: Maybe an access token issue …?

Comment: Well in the end it just seems to return id for some venues and name for others. So I'll just offer venue data when the id is available.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue today and spent quite some time troubleshooting it. It seems to be related to the Access Token. When I use my App's Access Token to request the venue data, for some venues all I I get is the venue.name field. However, if I use the Graph API Explorer to generate a different token, I get the venue.id field as expected.

I went as far as to replace the Graph API Explorer's generated Access Token with my App Token, and sure enough all I received back was venue.name.